# Connected sets in a binary matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose we have a binary matrix

```
0 0 1 1 0 
0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 1
```

and I want to find out the largest area of connected `1`s

in this case it's

```
0 0 1 1 0 
0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Does MATLAB have some function to do so or I have to create one?

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not here to write your code and [recommendation questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) are off-topic here. Please try something first and if you get stuck on a specific thing, upload your code in a [mcve], so we can help you.

Comment: If you have the image processing toolbox then [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) will get you most of the way there.

Comment: I am not here to ask for code. Just wondering is there a functions in MATLab so I can do this easily

Comment: @Cyrus as I said in my previous comment, that is alas off-topic on SO, since they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. It is therefore required to add the code you have tried and you're stuck with. PS: it's "MATLAB" officially

Comment: thanks guys, I will try Dan's option first. @Adriaan Sorry I haven't read the rule here. I will do so if i ask next time

Comment: @Cyrus cool! We're always happy to receive interesting questions, so stick around and good luck.